# What's the meaning of the right multiplication of the GLM transform functions?

Tags: c++, glm-math

I encountered some problems when using matrix multiplication to transform the coordinates of a point, which made me realize that the default multiplication order of the glm transform functions are opposite to what I need.

The test code is as follows:

```cpp
#define GLM_FORCE_RADIANS
#define GLM_FORCE_DEPTH_ZERO_TO_ONE
#define GLM_ENABLE_EXPERIMENTAL

#include <iostream>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/ext/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

void Print(const std::string &title, glm::vec3 point) {
  std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3)
            << title << ": " << point.x << ", " << point.y << ", " << point.z << std::endl;
}

glm::vec3 RotateAroundPointA(glm::vec3 ori_point, glm::vec3 center, float rotation_x, float rotation_y) {
  std::cout << "-- RotateAroundPointA ----------------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;

  auto transform = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1), -center);
  auto curr_point = transform * glm::vec4(ori_point, 1);
  Print("Recenter ", curr_point);

  transform = glm::rotate(transform, rotation_x, glm::vec3(1, 0, 0));
  curr_point = transform * glm::vec4(ori_point, 1);
  Print("RotateX  ", curr_point);

  transform = glm::rotate(transform, rotation_y, glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
  curr_point = transform * glm::vec4(ori_point, 1);
  Print("RotateY  ", curr_point);

  transform = glm::translate(transform, center);
  curr_point = transform * glm::vec4(ori_point, 1);
  Print("Move back", curr_point);

  curr_point = transform * glm::vec4(ori_point, 1);
  Print("Returned ", curr_point);
  return curr_point;
}

glm::vec3 RotateAroundPointB(glm::vec3 ori_point, glm::vec3 center, float rotation_x, float rotation_y) {
  std::cout << "-- RotateAroundPointB ----------------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;

  auto recenter = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1), -center);
  auto curr_point = recenter * glm::vec4(ori_point, 1);
  Print("Recenter ", curr_point);

  auto rotate_x = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1), rotation_x, glm::vec3(1, 0, 0));
  curr_point = rotate_x * curr_point;
  Print("RotateX  ", curr_point);

  auto rotate_y = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1), rotation_y, glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
  curr_point = rotate_y * curr_point;
  Print("RotateY  ", curr_point);

  auto move_back = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1), center);
  curr_point = move_back * curr_point;
  Print("Move back", curr_point);

  curr_point = move_back * rotate_y * rotate_x * recenter * glm::vec4(ori_point, 1);
  Print("Returned ", curr_point);
  return curr_point;
}

TEST (GlmTests, Default) {
  const glm::vec3 kCenter{1, 1, 1};
  const glm::vec3 kOriPoint(kCenter.x, kCenter.y, kCenter.z + 1);
  const auto kOriDistance = glm::distance(kOriPoint, kCenter);
  const auto kPi = glm::pi<float>();

  auto curr_point = RotateAroundPointA(kOriPoint, kCenter, kPi / 4, kPi / 4);
  EXPECT_FLOAT_EQ(kOriDistance, glm::distance(curr_point, kCenter));

  curr_point = RotateAroundPointB(kOriPoint, kCenter, kPi / 4, kPi / 4);
  EXPECT_FLOAT_EQ(kOriDistance, glm::distance(curr_point, kCenter));
}
```

The output is:

```
-- RotateAroundPointA ----------------------------------------------------------
Recenter : 0.000, 0.000, 1.000
RotateX  : 0.000, -1.707, 1.121
RotateY  : 1.121, -0.793, 0.207
Move back: 2.536, -0.086, 0.914
Returned : 2.536, -0.086, 0.914
D:\cpp\test20\test\glm_tests.cpp(70): error: Expected equality of these values:
  kOriDistance
    Which is: 1
  glm::distance(curr_point, kCenter)
    Which is: 1.8825928
-- RotateAroundPointB ----------------------------------------------------------
Recenter : 0.000, 0.000, 1.000
RotateX  : 0.000, -0.707, 0.707
RotateY  : 0.500, -0.707, 0.500
Move back: 1.500, 0.293, 1.500
Returned : 1.500, 0.293, 1.500
```

I googled and found someone said:

> Note that GLM transformation functions, like glm::rotate, apply the transformation on the right; i.e.
>
> ```cpp
> m = m * glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::radians(5.f), axis);
> ```

So, what is the reason that GLM is designed to have the opposite order as compared to the general matrix multiplication?

Comment: OpenGL Mathematics (GLM) is designed to work in the same way as GLSL. See [GLSL Programming/Vector and Matrix Operations](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/Vector_and_Matrix_Operations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't the "opposite order"; it is the *correct* order... from a certain point of view.

What we're doing is right-multiplication. That means if you have a transform T and you want to transform a point P by it, you perform `T * P`.

So if you have two transforms T1 and T2, if you do this: `T2 * (T1 * P)`, then that means "transform P by T1, then transform the result by T2". Matrix multiplication is associative, so that's equivalent to `(T2 * T1) * P`.

So if you want to transform P by T1 then T2, you would build the appropriate matrix by generating T2, then right-multiplying T1 into it. If you have 3 transforms in sequence from T1 to T2 to T3, you do `((T3 * T2) * T1)`.

It is the correct order relative to how you intend to transform your vectors. The first transform you build is the last one that gets applied to the point.

Comment: Indeed, this order is the same as writing `*` directly. However, I thought that since it is much like object-based operation, GLM would use a more user-friendly order to reduce the burden of coding. Otherwise we should use `*` directly instead of passing in the previous matrix.

Comment: @pellorao: It is a "user-friendly order", as long as the user understands what they're doing. A user who is used to the way `glPushMatrix`, `glTranslate`, etc works would be right at home. Equally importantly, the GLM functions are all *template* functions; they could take a 3x3 matrix or a 4x4 matrix or various other matrices. By passing a matrix as an input, it can deduce what kind of matrix to generate as an output. If you didn't pass that in, you would have to specify the matrix type as an explicit template parameter.

Comment: @pellorao: It also allows one function to do some of the later transformations, then pass that matrix to some other function that will apply more recent transforms, then to others that will apply the first transforms. Imagine a parent-to-child relationship, with the parents applying their transforms, then passing copies of those matrices to the children. My point is that the order is very intuitive once you start doing real stuff with matrices.